# Make only some features dummyVars

Tags: r, r-caret

```
my_diamonds <- diamonds %>% mutate(cut = as.character(cut),
                                   color = as.character(color),
                                   clarity = as.character(clarity))
```

I would like to create a new dataframe with just cut and color as dummyVars.

However, I cannot get the first block in the below code to work:

```
# make cut and color dummar vars
dummy <- caret::dummyVars("cut + color",
                            data = my_diamonds, fullRank = F, sep = ".")

# now create the dummy vars as new dataframe training data
training_data <- predict(dummy, my_diamonds) %>% as.data.frame()
```

This piece:

```
# make cut and color dummar vars
dummy <- caret::dummyVars("cut + color",
                            data = my_diamonds, fullRank = F, sep = ".")
```

Gives:
Error in eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]]) : 
  object 'color' not found.

Also tried:

```
dummy <- caret::dummyVars(~ "cut + color",
                            data = my_diamonds, fullRank = F, sep = ".")
```

Which gives:
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars

How can I create a new dataframe based on my_diamonds where cut and color are dummy vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small issue: `~ "cut + color"` should instead be `"~ cut + color"` or just `~ cut + color`:

```
dummy <- caret::dummyVars(~ cut + color,
                          data = my_diamonds, fullRank = FALSE, sep = ".")
training_data <- predict(dummy, my_diamonds) %>% as.data.frame()
head(training_data)
#   cutFair cutGood cutIdeal cutPremium cutVery Good colorD colorE colorF colorG colorH colorI colorJ
# 1       0       0        1          0            0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
# 2       0       0        0          1            0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
# 3       0       1        0          0            0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
# 4       0       0        0          1            0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
# 5       0       1        0          0            0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
# 6       0       0        0          0            1      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
```